# Having trouble using mingw to install python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, mingw

I've spent hours googling this, but haven't been able to find any answers.  I'm trying to install a package for Python 3.4, but keep running into problems.  First, I tried just running "python setup.py install":

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
error: Python was built with Visual Studio 2003;
extensions must be built with a compiler than can generate compatible binaries.
Visual Studio 2003 was not found on this system. If you have Cygwin installed,
you can try compiling with MingW32, by passing "-c mingw32" to setup.py.
```

After a long time of searching, I downloaded mingw, added C:/MinGW/bin to my path, made sure MinGW has gcc, and made my distutils.cfg file with [build] and compiler = mingw32 in it.  On running python setup.py install again, I got the same error.

I tried what it suggested, passing -c mingw32 to setup.py.  It can't do it for setup.py install, so I did setup.py build:

```
python setup.py build -c mingw32
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
```

That all seems well and good, but when I try to install after building it tries to build it all over again, and because I can't pass in the compiler for some reason it fails.

How can I get setup.py to work?  If it helps, I'm trying to install the [noise](https://github.com/caseman/noise) package, and am using Windows Vista 64-bit (I don't have much money...).

Comment: You can download binaries from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Yup. You are in luck. Noise is available.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues recently.

Some tips for Windows builds:

- Check your Python binary at a Windows command prompt: `where.exe python.exe`

  - Did you forget to activate a virtualenv?
- Check your env vars: `%PYTHONPATH%` and `%PYTHONHOME%`

  - Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables
- Clean-up a previous build: `python setup.py clean --all`

  - If you forget the `--all`, it is useless for most use cases.  (More like a dusting.)
- View `setup.py` online help.

  - For `setup.py`: `python setup.py --help`
  - For `build` command:  `python setup.py build --help`
  - For `install` command:  `python setup.py install --help`
  - For `clean` command:  `python setup.py clean --help`
- Order of operations should be: clean (optional), build, install

  - Clean: `python setup.py clean --all`
  - Build: `python setup.py build` (Optional argument: `-c mingw32`)
  - Install: `python setup.py install --record files.txt`
  - The optional arguments `--record files.txt` help to uninstall if you broken something.
  - After install, check the folder `Libs\site-packages` for the Python installation.  Do you see the package?  Usually, you can see `*.pyd` files, which are similar to DLLs.
- Never underestimate the complexity of build and run environments.  (I often make this mistake.)  It is easy to have a single, errant environment variable break a build or run.

  - Open a new command prompt before the build.
  - Open a new command prompt for the test run after install.